# I can't see deletes but this looks familiar

Tags: discussion

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/331919/131624

Reminds me of

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331878/deploying-multiple-wars-on-one-server-instance-vs-each-on-a-server

and

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/99553/deploying-multiple-wars-small-websites

I can't see the deleted question but this seems awfully familiar.  How do I flag in a case like this?

Comment: I left a couple of comments on his remaining question, and voted to close it. I didn't flag for moderator attention.

Comment: Well, after some words with the OP, I've changed my mind, and flagged for moderator attention.  The OP is being a bit abusive, relying on us being too slow to close the question before getting his answer, and the question really isn't a very good one for this site anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to flag here:

- If you feel the question is off topic, vote to close it.
- If you feel it's a poor question, downvote it.
- If you wish to help the OP understand what they are doing wrong, comment.

If the OP continues ignoring the signs that their question isn't quite welcome here, the automated question ban will kick in and resolve the situation.

---

As for the ProWebmasters question, Programmers mods aren't able to do more about it than you. Again, no reason to flag.

Comment: What is this "automated question ban" that you speak of?  While the algorithm on Stack Overflow does sort of do what you describe, it doesn't act on a single question unless it is particularly bad (i.e. downvotes in the double-digits or spam flags), and I'm not even sure that mechanism is turned on here.  No, this is a mod decision, if the community can't be arsed to close it, not a decision for an automated process.  You weren't given a binding close vote without also being given the authority to use it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Posts bans are enabled here. And notice that I only mention the q-ban "if the OP continues ignoring the signs that their question isn't quite welcome", i.e. continues re-posting their question.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm still asking for a question closure, though (and a comments purge).  Whether the community can't decide, or it's just the weekend, I don't really see any good reason for that post to hang around any longer than it already has.

Comment: Deleted the whole thing @RobertHarvey. I was hoping the first couple of comments you posted would get through, but that's obviously not going to happen.